# Series with denominator that is square of product of consecutive numbers

Tags: summation

Evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2(k+1)^2}$.

I've tried to use a telescoping approach, but it doesn't seem to work. It doesn't also seem to converge to a "pretty" value as well.

Answer (score 3):

Partial fractions decomposition give us
\begin{align*}
\frac1{x^2(x+1)^2}&=-\frac{2}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{2}{x+1}+\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}
\end{align*}

Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2(k+1)^2}&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac2{k+1}-\frac2k\right)+\sum_{k=1}^n\left[\frac1{k^2}+\frac1{(k+1)^2}\right]\\[3pt]
&=\frac2{n+1}-2+\frac1{(n+1)^2}+2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2}-1
\end{align*}
Where we have used the fact that the first sum on the RHS is telescopic. So
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2(k+1)^2}=2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2}+\frac{2n+3}{(n+1)^2}-3$$

Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{k^2(k+1)^2}&=2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{k^2}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{2n+3}{(n+1)^2}-3\right]\\[3pt]
&=2\cdot\frac{\pi^2}6+(0-3)\\
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{k^2(k+1)^2}&=\boxed{\color{blue}{\frac{\pi^2}3-3}}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

*This is too long for a comment. It has been added for your curiosity.*

Ángel Mario Gallegos having given the good solution to the problem, let me address the problem of the partial sums starting from what Ángel Mario Gallegos wrote
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2(k+1)^2}=2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2}+\frac{2n+3}{(n+1)^2}-3$$ But, $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2}=H_n^{(2)}$$ where appear the generalized harmonic numbers. This makes $$S_n=2H_n^{(2)}+\frac{2n+3}{(n+1)^2}-3$$ For large values of $n$, we can use the asymptotics $$H_n^{(a)}=n^{-a} \left(-\frac{n}{a-1}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{a}{12 n}+\frac{a^3+3 a^2+2 a}{720
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)+\zeta (a)$$ which, in the present case, reduces to $$H_n^{(2)}=\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2 n^2}-\frac{1}{6
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ Continuing the expansion for the other terms, we should get $$S_n=\left(\frac{\pi ^2}{3}-3\right)-\frac{1}{3
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Using $n=10$, we should find $$S_{10}=\frac{22254209}{76839840}\approx 0.289618$$ while the approximation would give $$\frac{\pi ^2}{3}-3-\frac 1{3000}\approx 0.289535$$